# Why can't I authenticate an https request using a client certificate in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, https, client-certificates

- I'm writing an iOS application using XCode 12.
- I'm using native APIs (`URLSession`, `URLSessionDelegate`, etc.).
- I'm reading the [SecIdentity](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/secidentity) from a pfx12 blob.
- There doesn't seem to be any problem with the `SecIdentity`. It loads with no errors, and debugging shows that it's not nil.
- It happens when I'm running my app in the simulator almost all of the time. I've actually had it work before with this implementation, but the simulator seems to get into a state where it starts happening, and then I can't get it to work again.
- It does it when I connect an iPhone to the development computer and run it on that as well.
- If I make the HTTPS request with insomnia, configured with the same client certificate, it works every time. Clearly there is something different about the way my app makes the request, but I don't know what it is.

Here is my URLSessionDelegate implementation. As you can see, it responds to the `NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate` with a URLCredential created by using the client certificate identity:

```swift
fileprivate class SecureURLSessionDelegate: NSObject, URLSessionDelegate {
  private let identity: SecIdentity
  
  // nocov
  init(withIdentity identity: SecIdentity) {
    self.identity = identity
  }
  
  // maybecov
  func urlSession(_ session: URLSession,
                  didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge,
                  completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
    if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate {
      print("challenge identity: \(String(describing: self.identity))")
      let credential = URLCredential(identity: self.identity,
                                     certificates: nil,
                                     persistence: .forSession)
      print("responding with credential: \(credential.debugDescription)")
      completionHandler(.useCredential, credential)
    } else {
      completionHandler(.performDefaultHandling, nil)
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my initialization of the URLSession

```swift
extension URLSession {
  convenience init(identity: SecIdentity, token: String) {
    print("using identity: \(String(describing: identity))")
    self.init(
      configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.secured(withToken: token),
      delegate: SecureURLSessionDelegate(withIdentity: identity),
      delegateQueue: nil)
  }
}
```

Here is the unsuccessful HTTPS request implementation

```swift
private static func fetchAPIData(identity: SecIdentity, token: String, url: URL) -> AnyPublisher<Data, Error> {
    let session = URLSession(identity: identity, token: token)
    return session.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
      .handleEvents(
        receiveCompletion: { _ in
          session.finishTasksAndInvalidate()
        },
        receiveCancel: {
          session.finishTasksAndInvalidate()
        })
      .eraseToAnyPublisher()
  }
```

Here's the result I get from the `session.dataTaskPublisher()` call

```
2021-07-30 14:44:56.936388-0700 SmoothBanking[41075:40401540] Task <1BAD4C76-7FA2-40D0-8A0B-93B5425C035C>.<1> finished with error [-1206] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1206 "The server “api.teller.io” requires a client certificate." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The server “api.teller.io” requires a client certificate., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.teller.io/accounts, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.teller.io/accounts, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <1BAD4C76-7FA2-40D0-8A0B-93B5425C035C>.<1>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <1BAD4C76-7FA2-40D0-8A0B-93B5425C035C>.<1>, NSUnderlyingError=0x600003a51f80 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1206 "(null)" UserInfo={NSErrorPeerAddressKey=<CFData 0x600001768370 [0x10d594b90]>{length = 16, capacity = 16, bytes = 0x100201bb2ce9e7b50000000000000000}}}}
```

What am I missing? I even verified that it's running the delegate, and as far as I can tell it's supplying the credential, yet it just doesn't work.

Comment: "the simulator seems to get into a state where it starts happening"  It does't explain what that state is, does it?

Comment: "I'm reading the SecIdentity from a pfx12 blob"  Nobody even knows what a guy named 'SecIdentity' is.

Comment: The server is telling you, he does not trust the identity without certificates.